# Проблема с билдом моего проекта в Unity, ошибка в Android license

Tags: unity3d, android-studio, android-sdk

Я хотел собрать свой проект, но столкнулся с ошибкой.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':unityLibrary'.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.sdk.LicenceNotAcceptedException: Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licenses have not been accepted. ndk;23.1.7779620 NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager. All licenses can be accepted using the sdkmanager command line tool: sdkmanager --licenses Or, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#download-with-gradle

Using Android SDK: D:\Unity\Hub\Editor\2023.2.9f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK

*Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 6s

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

Чтобы ее исправить, мне нужно ввести команду sdkmanager --licenses. Перед этим я загрузил и установил все необходимое в Android Studio, следуя инструкциям из других руководств по решению этой проблемы. Затем я перешел в каталог C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Android \Sdk\tools\bin>, где ввел эту команду и получил ошибку.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.(SchemaModule.java:156) at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.(SchemaModule.java:75) at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81) at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73) at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ... 5 more

Я также попробовал ввести эту команду в PowerShell, но там ошибка

sdkmanager : Имя "sdkmanager" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Пров
проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1

- sdkmanager --licenses
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sdkmanager:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Suggestion [3,General]: Команда sdkmanager не найдена, однако существует в текущем расположении. По умолчанию оболочка Windows PowerShell не загружает команды из текущего расположения. Если вы уверены в надежности команды, введите ".\sdkmanager". Для получения дополнительных сведений вызовите справку с помощью команды "get-help about_Command_Precedence".

Перед этим я попробовал всё возможное: загрузил новые файлы, переустановил и изучил разные руководства, чтобы решить эту проблему. Я загрузил все файлы из инструментов sdk в менеджере SDK, но ошибка осталась. Ребята, мне действительно нужна помощь. Эта ошибка появилась после перехода на новую версию, и я уже работаю над проектом 2 месяца. До этого всё было в порядке, и мне действительно нужно решить эту проблему со сборкой. Помогите пожалуйста

---

[image: Вот скриншот вкладки настроек Preferences]

Мне нужно написать тут не менее 30 символов, так что я просто хочу пожелать вам здоровья, Может быть мне нужно В самой Unity что-то сделать кстати, или может ещё какой-то способ, но я очень надеюсь что вы мне поможете

Answer (score 0):

При установке юнити через UnityHub у вас есть опция установить android sdk и перед началом установки установщик вас спрашивает принятия лицензионного соглашения. В вашем случае, вероятно вы используете внешний sdk в котором лицензия не была принята. Откройте меню Unity > Preferences и перейдя в раздел External Tools окна настроек и попробуйте выбрать установленый sdk от android studio или используйте тот который поставляется вместе с unity, переустановив unity перед этим(приняв лицензионное соглашение)

Comment: Проясните пожалуйста, я зашёл в UnityHub и нажал на значок настроек Preferences, но там нигде нету External Tools

Comment: в окошке preferences слева вкладка external tools должна быть

Comment: вот смотрите я приложу картинку, я не вижу тут external tools, может быть у меня не та версия

Comment: На картинке UnityHub, вам нужно это сделать в открытьп проекте самого юнити.